# Apple Music Smart Playlist not syncing correctly with iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-music, smart-playlist

I've just created a very simple Smart Playlist that selects all my "Loved" songs. That's it, not referencing other playlists, not referencing any song outside my library, no nested rules. Just "Love is Loved" as a condition. The playlist on my computer shows 166 songs, but the same playlist on my iPhone shows 144 songs. I've checked for some of the missing songs on my iPhone and they are in the Library and I can play them on my phone, no problem. They just won't appear on that Smart Playlist. Any tips?

I have all the latest updated software as of today (Jan 8th 2019) both on my computer and on my phone. I have both Apple Music and iTunes in the Cloud enabled on my phone and on my computer. If I update the playlist name, it gets automatically updated on my phone as well. If I "like" a new song, that song gets added to the playlist on the phone too. It seems to me that only some songs that were already liked when I created the playlist that are missing.

Comment: I believe I may have found a fix. If I uncheck a song as "loved" and re-check it, it gets added to my phone. So apparently what is out of sync here is what songs are checked as loved on my phone and on my computer. Re-doing it either on my computer or on my phone will resync everything. I haven't done it on all of my missing songs yet, but it appears to be consistent so far.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that somehow my library was the one out of sync. Songs that my computer thought were marked as liked were not marked as liked on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

A song *loved* on your computer doesn't mostly show up as *loved* on your iphone, while a song *loved* on an iphone is always showed as *loved* on a computer version of Apple Music.

Solution is to first add the song to your library on your computer and then *loved* it. Then it's auto synced to your iPhone.